# IIS 7.5 ASP.Net and remote share

Tags: asp.net, iis, impersonation, network-shares

I have an issue with our ASP.net application not being able to read files from a remote directory. Our users log into our application using Forms Authentication, so no AD accounts are used in logging them in.

I have added the machine accounts the machines to the share, as I have a local service on the machine that can write to it and a SQL server able to read/write to the share with a machine account.

However, our asp.net app, running on the same server as the service above, is is not able to do this. I have tried impersonation set to true, but this does not work unless I provide an AD account. Once provided, the share works fine.

I can't move the share to the IIS server due to size constraints.

Is there anyway to allow easy access or do I need to take the interop approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The account the application pool runs under needs access on the remote folder. Add that account to the security tab(not only share tab) of the remote folder.

Or, try running the apppool as the AD account you used for impersonation.

Comment: If I understand you right, you're saying I should add the server + the Iis app pool user to the security screen? 
I'm assuming this would be like this: 192.168.1.2\IIS_IUSRS for the group?

Comment: Setting the app pool to run under that user will probably be the easiest and one-shot fix for this though. I'll get our admin to create a special account and lock it down.